# Window Manager parent-children relationship weird behavior in python PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

What I want to achieve in python PyQt5 is when I open the script I open a parent window automatically with a button on the middle of the screen. When I click this button a new window suppose to open, and when I close the window I can close separately the parent window and the child window. I want to be able to close the parent window first. I've done that and it works but there is a weird behavior when I open more than 10 windows sometimes when I close a window it recreates another window by itself, and sometimes one of the windows closes all of the other opened windows. How to fix this issue, the code has no errors, but it does not work as intended.

I've tried to convert the first child window to a parent window, and if all parent windows are closed the remaining child windows to become parent. This is somewhat successful, but not what I want. Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class WindowManager(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super().__init__(parent)

      self.button = QPushButton("Create New Window", self)
      self.button.clicked.connect(self.new_window)
      self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

      self.children = []

      if self.parent() is not None and len(self.parent().children) > 0 and self.parent().children[0] == self:
       self.is_first_child = True
      else:
       self.is_first_child = False

    def new_window(self):

        window_manager = WindowManager(self)

        window_manager.resize(self.size())

        window_manager.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)

        window_manager.setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)

        window_manager.create_new_window_on_close = True

        self.children.append(window_manager)

        window_manager.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
      if self.parent() is None:
        if self.children:
            if all(child.parent() is not None for child in self.children):
                self.children[0].setParent(None)
                self.children[0].setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)
                self.children[0].setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)
                self.children[0].show()
                self.children[0].children = self.children[1:]
        self.close()
      else:
        if self in self.parent().children:
            self.parent().children.remove(self)
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window_manager = WindowManager()
    window_manager.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Code 2 :

```
import sys
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QMenu,
    QMenuBar,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Another Window % d" % randint(0, 100))
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.windows1 = []
        
        menubar = self.menuBar()
       
        self.file_menu = menubar.addMenu("File")

        self.button1 = QPushButton("New")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.create_window1)
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.button1.text(), lambda: self.create_window1())

    def create_window1(self):
        window = QMainWindow(None)  
        window.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)  
        menubar = window.menuBar()
        menubar.addMenu(self.file_menu)
        self.windows1.append(window)
        window.show()
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your script to fix the bugs, but I removed some unused parts:

- `is_first_child` flag
- `create_new_window_on_close` flag
- Unused `QKeySequence`, `QAction` and `QFileDialog` imports

---

The main problem I found about was the `WindowManager.children` reference which messed up in the code. From what I could understand, only the parent should contain the current reference to the `children` list with updated data. Whenever the parent would be closed, this updated reference should be passed into one of the children.

**The main flaw** was in this line:

```
def new_window(self):
    # ... code ...

    self.children.append(window_manager)

    # ... code ...
```

You're always inserting a new child into the current's instance reference of `child`. That is, if you click on the child `QPushButton`, you're never updating the parent's `children` list. You're always updating the current instance one.

In short words: it got confusing. So I reworked that into using a single shared list between all instances of `WindowManager`. Whenever a parent window is created, it creates it's own list. Whenever a child is created, it acquires the parent's list reference.

Here's my version of your script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from random import randint

# Store taken indexes
taken = []

# If you're on Windows, this might not work unless you use another terminal
# application that allows ansi colors. (default windows console does not
# support it)
red = '\033[91m%s\033[0m'
green = '\033[92m%s\033[0m'

# With this we can open 1000 different windows on our testing environment
# ensuring each window contains a different index value
def uniqueIndex():
    idx = randint(0, 1000)
    while (idx in taken):
        idx = randint(0, 1000)
    taken.append(idx)
    return idx

class WindowManager(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Get an unique identifier (only for testing)
        self.index = uniqueIndex()

        # If this instance is the parent, create a new shared reference.
        if (parent is None):
            self.children = []

        # Otherwise, acquire the reference from the parent window, and add
        # itself inside it.
        else:
            self.children = parent.children
        
        # print on terminal that we're adding a window
        print('%s %d' % (green % 'Adding: ', self.index))

        # Update the window title, and add it to the shared children list
        self.update_parent(parent)
        self.children.append(self)

        self.button = QPushButton("Create New Window", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.new_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        self.setMinimumWidth(300)

    def new_window(self):
        window_manager = WindowManager(self)
        window_manager.resize(self.size())
        window_manager.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)
        window_manager.setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)
        window_manager.show()

    # Used just for testing.
    def update_parent(self, parent=None):
        if (parent is None):
            self.setWindowTitle('Parent %d' % self.index)
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle('Parent %d: Index %d' % (parent.index, self.index))

        self.setParent(parent)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Remove the self from the shared children list
        self.children.remove(self)

        # print on the terminal that we're removing a window
        print('%s: %d' % (red % 'Removing:', self.index))

        # If the array is not empty:
        if (self.children):

            # Reparent all children based on the current parent (which can be None)
            for child in self.children:
                if (child.parent() == self):
                    child.update_parent(self.parent())

                # set parent clears all window flags.
                child.setWindowModality(Qt.NonModal)
                child.setWindowFlag(Qt.Window)

                # ensure the child is visible
                child.show()

        # Ensure we're closing the current window.
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window_manager = WindowManager()
    window_manager.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks Carl HR, your code is much cleaner but the script has the same behavior, after I open 10-15 windows from different previously opened windows (for example to test the script I've opened 3 win's from the main parent window, and then 3 from one of the children win's, and then 3 from their children children win's etc...) and at some point when I close some of the win's they open on pressing the close button, and sometimes they close all together. The only workaround I've found is to hide the main parent window with self.hide() event.ignore() , but then the script remains open all the time.

Comment: Are you testing this application with another application behind it (such as your IDE, console, etc)? Or are you testing with the desktop behind it? Sometimes when I open too many windows, separate them from each other, and then minimize them, as there are too many, the windows don't show some of them anymore, until when you close one and it's a parent window which it calls `self.children[0].show()` inside it's closeEvent. As show is called, the window is forced to reappear again on the desktop, giving the illusion of being created out of nowhere.

Comment: @kru3 can you verify if that's what's happening here? I tested the code and sometimes I did clicked too fast (and accidentally on the console behind all windows) making the windows disappear as you described. But not to have them open new windows from the closeEvent.

Comment: I've test it on Linux, I run the script from terminal, I can confirm the first part you've described. Carl HR: "{As show is called, the window is forced to reappear again on the desktop, giving the illusion of being created out of nowhere.}"

Comment: The second part no because I run the script from terminal so I was not clicking too fast but at some point some of the opened win's like let's say child of a child acts as parent and closes all of the other win's so I cannot confirm the following Carl HR "{I tested the code and sometimes I did clicked too fast (and accidentally on the console behind all windows) making the windows disappear as you described. But not to have them open new windows from the closeEvent.}" Can this be fixed somehow without hiding the main parent window but actually closing it?

Comment: @kru3 I tested the code again and yes the code still had bugs. Your last comment so far was right, there was a bug that made windows close based on their parent. I've updated the code now, hopefully it fixes the bug. Whenever a child's parent is removed, the parent is either reparented to the parent's parent, or None (becoming a parent with no parent). Just so you know, whenever you close a widget and its children vanishes, they do not: they teleport into the new parent's position. So the windows might be on top of each other instantly.

Comment: Hi Carl HR, now it got even weirder, at some point logs me out of my Linux session. I guess this is due different environments. Multiple windows are still closing at some point, and also the first bug with reappearing windows out of nowhere. Ansi is fine.

Comment: @kru3 the windows will only close if the print in red shows up on the terminal (that's what's instructed to happen on the script). Are you saying the windows are really closing (the red print appears for their own ID), or just hiding themselves (only the parent's ID appears on the terminal) when using the updated code? Also, what do you mean about login out of your linux session? I can't test that because I'm use Windows 10. What's your linux version btw?

Comment: @kru3 when you wrote this report, did you test the minimal reproducible example I provided here, or did you test your own script (with more variables, modules, logic added into it)?

Comment: I've found a workaround and I posted it as Code 2. This code works best of what I wanted to achieve, but it is still not perfect. What I want now is when I close the "Main Window" the whole script to exit but the window1 to remain open and continue to work as normal until the user closes it while the script(app) is already exited.

Comment: @kru3 If you want to ask a whole different thing from the current question, I suggest you to create a new post with this new question.